# location of first visible pixel in window? (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I dont't know how to put that, but I need y coordinates of the first pixel that is visible in window when I scroll down.

thanks,
Mladen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```